# "Explaining" a coincidental connection between Pascal's triangle and symmetries of lattices

Tags: binomial-coefficients, integer-lattices, vector-lattices, crystallography

The $1$s on the edges of Pascal's triangle appear infinitely many times in the array.

One number ‒ just one ‒ appears exactly once.

Infinitely many have multiplicity $2.$

Infinitely many have multiplicity $3.$

Infinitely many have multiplicity $4.$

Infinitely many have multiplicity $6.$

One is known to have multiplicity $8;$ whether any others do is unknown.

Whether any odd multiplicities more than $3$ occur is unknown.

[Singmaster's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singmaster%27s_conjecture) is that the set of multiplicities is bounded, so it may be that no multiplicities exceeding $8$ occur.

(The one known to have multiplicity $8$ is $\dbinom{3003} 1 = \dbinom{78} 2 = \dbinom{15} 5 = \dbinom{14} 6.$)

- The multiplicities known to occur infinitely many times are $2,3,4,6.$
- The only rotational symmetries of a two-dimensional lattice are of order $2,$ $3,$ $4,$ or $6.$

Might there be some connection between the two problems that explains why that same set of numbers appears? (Here's a wild fantasy: Prove the statement about Pascal's triangle by using the statement about symmetries of lattices.)

Comment: I have added ([tag:integer-lattices]) tag - please correct this if needed. The tag ([tag:vector-lattices]) is for [questions about vector spaces with lattice structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/vector-lattices/info) - such as Riesz spaces or Banach lattices. What you describe seems to me closer to the [description of the integer-lattices tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/integer-lattices/info).